# Can create the getter and setter method private?

Tags: java

Can create the setter and getter method private ? If yes or no why?

Comment: You are asking whether getter and setter can be made private or you want to know the pros-and cons of making getter and setters as private methods?

Comment: Only asking can create the getter and setter private?

Comment: Yes, you can. There is no restriction on that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally making setters as private methods is one of the many ways of making `immutable objects.`

Comment: Why even make a setter then, when any code that can call the setter can directly modify the private variable as well, and override any sort of checks the setter might make.

Comment: You will probably loose the checks the setters/getters might do, modifying the state variable directly. Private setter/getter is thoughtful solution only for these kinds of additional checks.

Comment: If I wanted to make an object immutable, I would (among other things) make its properties final.  Then it could not have a setter method.

Comment: @Enomy : Yeah that's another strategy of making immutable objects by creating final and private fields.

Comment: Declaring all setters private is *not sufficient* to make an object immutable.  If you have any setters (public or private) you *also* need some scheme to prevent the setter from changing the object state after the object *becomes* immutable.

Answer (score 1):

> Can create the setter and getter method private ? If yes or no why?

1)  Yes you *can* do it.

2)  The reason that you *can* do it is because the Java Language Specification says you can.  As far as the JLS is concerned, there is nothing linguistically different between getter and setter methods and any other methods.  And *any* method *can* be declared as private.

Your unstated question is why you *would* do it.  And the reason is simple: to hide the methods from use outside of the class.  And why might you do that?  Here's a typical use-case:

We want to combine some logic (in this case enforcing of a constraint) with the setting (or getting) of an attribute, but we don't want the setter (or getter) to be visible:

```
public class Foo {
    private Foo parent;  // this must not change once it has been set
    ....
    private void setParent(Foo parent) {
        if (this.parent != null) {
            throw new SomeException(...);
        }
        this.parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but there is hardly a point. If those methods are private then any code that can call those methods can also access the objects properties directly.

Comment: I assume that any code that can call those methods is under my control.  I choose how to acces the objects properties and I can choose to write a setter/getter convenience method to save myself the trouble of repeating the same code over and over again.

Comment: I have created a counter example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143564/can-create-the-getter-and-setter-method-private/7144089#7144089 - where some code that could access the setter/getter methods could not access the objects properties directly.  Admittedly, it still seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, getters and setters can be made private. If you want to create a [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean), then a private getter/setter fails the JavaBeans criteria, which states:

> The class properties **must** be accessible using *get*, *set*, *is* (used for
>   boolean properties instead of *get*) and other methods (so-called
>   accessor methods and mutator methods), following a standard
>   naming-convention. This allows easy automated inspection and updating
>   of bean state within frameworks, many of which include custom editors
>   for various types of properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can not make getters and setters private.

Why would you do this? If the setter method modified a property indirectly.  For example, if your circle class had a radius property, then you could have setRadius, setDiameter, setCircumference, setArea methods and you could choose to make these methods private.

In fact, if you insert some convoluted code, you can have code that can call these setter/getter methods that can not modify the properties directly (without using reflection).  But it is sufficiently convoluted that it seems hardly worth the trouble.

```
/**
 * This convoluted class will not work correctly unless the line "this . xRef . set ( x )" is line 10 and the line "x = this . xRef . get ( ) ;" is line 23
 **/
class Private
{
    private void setX ( int x )
    {
    try
        {
        this . xRef . set ( x ) ;
        }
    catch ( IllegalAccessException cause )
        {
        assert false ;
        }
    }

    private int getX ( )
    {
    int x ;
    try
        {
        x = this . xRef . get ( ) ;
        }
    catch ( IllegalAccessException cause )
        {
        x = 0 ;
        assert false ;
        }
    return x ;
    }

    private final Reference < Integer > xRef = new Reference < Integer > ( )
    {
        @ Override
        public Integer get ( ) throws IllegalAccessException
        {
        checkMethod ( "Private" , "getX" , 23 ) ;
        return super . get ( ) ;
        }

        @ Override
        public void set ( Integer val ) throws IllegalAccessException
        {
        checkMethod ( "Private" , "setX" , 10 ) ;
        super . set ( val ) ;
        }
    } ;

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
    Private p = new Private ( ) ;
    p . setX ( 5 ) ;
    System . out . println ( p . getX ( ) ) ;
    try
        {
        p . xRef . set ( 100 ) ;
        }
    catch ( IllegalAccessException cause )
        {
        cause . printStackTrace ( ) ;
        }
    System . out . println ( p . getX ( ) ) ;
    }
}

class Reference < T >
{
    private T val ;

    public void set ( T val ) throws IllegalAccessException
    {
    this . val = val ;
    }

    public T get ( ) throws IllegalAccessException
    {
    return this . val ;
    }

    public void checkMethod ( String className , String methodName , int lineNumber ) throws IllegalAccessException
    {
    IllegalAccessException cause = new IllegalAccessException ( ) ;
    boolean delta = true ;
    for ( StackTraceElement e : cause . getStackTrace ( ) )
        {
        if ( ( e . getClassName ( ) . equals ( className ) ) && ( e . getMethodName ( ) . equals ( methodName ) ) && ( e . getLineNumber ( ) == lineNumber ) )
            {
            delta = false ;
            break ;
            }
        }
    if ( delta )
        {
        throw cause ;
        }
    }
}
```